# can I display parameters value ($_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION, $_SESSION) using twig template engine component

Tags: php, twig

I had tried do like this :

```
{{ $_GET['page'] }}
```

but that still didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only variables available in Twig are:

- the ones you pass through the second parameter of [Twig_Environment#render()](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Environment.php#L286)
- the ones you pass by calling [Twig_Environment#addGlobal()](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Environment.php#L1025)

If you wish to have a `page` variable available, add `"page" => $_GET["page"]` to the second parameter of `render`.

If you wish to have the complete `$_GET` superglobal available, add `"GET" => $_GET` to the second parameter of `render`.

Answer (score 65):

For $_POST variables use this :

```
{{ app.request.parameter.get("page") }}
```

For $_GET variables use this :

```
{{ app.request.query.get("page") }}
```

For $_COOKIE variables use this :

```
{{ app.request.cookies.get("page") }}
```

For $_SESSION variables use this :

```
{{ app.request.session.get("page") }}
```

Comment: This is assuming you pass an "app" hash with these keys properly set up.

Comment: @Maerlyn this is symfony solution

Comment: @Jenechka the question is not tagged symfony, and nothing in the question suggests using it.

Comment: `Request` object has changed since '13. Nowadays you should use: `{{ app.request.request.get("page") }}` to retrieve POST `page` variable.

Comment: a bit misleading, looking for zf2 solution

Answer (score 7):

You cannot access raw PHP values in TWIG so you must attached anything that you need to the twig object.

Here is an example of attaching the `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_SESSION` to twig.

```
//initialise your twig object
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__PATH_TO_TEMPLATES_FOLDER__');
$this->twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);

$this->twig->addGlobal('_session', $_SESSION);
$this->twig->addGlobal('_post', $_POST);
$this->twig->addGlobal('_get', $_GET);
```

Now lets assume you have a value called `username` stored in each of the above (`$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_SESSION`)
You can now access all of these inside your template as follows.

```
 {{ _session.username }}
 {{ _post.username }}
 {{ _get.username }}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 6):

Another working solution @ 2019

```
app.request.get('page')
app.request.request.get('page')
```