# Text inputs not posted from HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, twig

I've been working on a simple ordering system with PHP and HTML forms. I'm not sure what's changed but suddenly even the simplest form is not including any inputs with type="text" in the form data sent to the script. So far I've checked that the inputs are all uniquely named and that max_input_vars is set to 1000, which is much higher than I need. Even making my form as simple as it can be still fails. When I submit the form below in Firefox (also tested in IE) the Form data section under the Params tab in Firefox's developer tools comments and action are shown correctly but first_name is not listed at all. I've tried changing the action to several different values but it makes no difference.

```
<h2>Place an Order</h2>
<form method="POST" action="">
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="32">
  {{first_name}}

  <label>Comments</label>
  <textarea name="comments" rows="3">{{comments}}</textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="btn" name="action" value="confirm">Confirm Order</button>
</form>
```

I am processing this with Twig for templating but it works correctly for the other fields and I can't see any reason why this would cause the form not to POST text input fields.

If I catch the submit event with jQuery and serialize the form all values are shown correctly.

I'm sure this is something really obvious I'm missing and perhaps I need more sleep but I just can't work out why it wouldn't submit text inputs. Even changing an email field from type="email" to type="text" caused it to be omitted from the POSTed data. Changing it back to type="email" fixed it immediately.

Does anyone have any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

#### Edit 1

I just tested it by adding a couple more fields and posting to a brand new script which just does a print_r($_POST). It printed out the values of a number field, email and textarea but not the text input fields.

#### Edit 2

It appears to break if I have an input field of type text outside the form regardless of whether that input is in a form of its own or not. The extra input is in a navigation bar beside the main content. The main form ignores all text inputs if the sidebar contains a text input. But they are contained in two separate forms so I can't see why they should interact like that. I'll do some more testing. I've got a feel for the pattern of when it breaks but I'm trying to pin it down to an exact behaviour now.

#### Edit 3

It consistently breaks (i.e. text inputs in the main form are omitted from the POST) *unless the first text input in the second form has a value in it*. It still breaks if the first input (in the source) is a type other than text but the first text input is empty. It doesn't matter which of the text inputs in the second form is first as long as the first text input in source order has a value in it. This is getting ridiculous, can anyone shed some light on this bizarre behaviour?

Comment: <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="32" value="{{first_name}}">

Comment: I realise that I need the first_name in the value attribute, I just pulled it out to make sure it couldn't interfere with the field at all. The first name doesn't seem to be sent at all and nothing shows up anywhere I put {{first_name}}. Doing a var_dump of $_POST shows that the script never receives a first name. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Does it print the correct value if you replace the `{{first_name}}` with an `echo $_POST['first_name'];`?

Comment: No, it just says that first_name is an undefined index. The script never gets the value at all.

Comment: oh man i hate it when stuff like this happens. my normal approach is to reboot everything, have a long slow coffee and see if that fixes it. works suprisingly often.

Comment: Wow, this one's a doozy. Does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554429/can-i-display-parameters-value-post-get-session-session-using-twig

Comment: Unfortunately not, even posting to a really basic script that's never heard of Twig fails to produce anything. It's as if the browser is ignoring the text fields for some reason. Rebooting didn't help, but I don't mind trying the coffee next.

Comment: It appears to be being caused by a second form on the page. When I delete the second form the problem goes away. The second form is pretty basic so I'm going to try rebuilding it and see if I can find the problem area.

Comment: You are using the label tag and not assigning it to anything.  For testing, remove the label tags and keep it as simple text prior to the input.  In edit 3, you said 'second form' and does this mean you have multiple forms, or did you mean second input?  Try testing with only 1 form active.  Post the controller that creates the form and the controller that handles it after its posted pls.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I removed the second form as it was not necessary to have it on that page and the problem and hence the urgency went away. I did mean a whole second form, not just a second input.