# Passing PHP global variables via Twig/Timber

Tags: twig, timber

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19554524/6450661, standard Twig provides a method via `{{ app.request }}` that I can use to pass $_GET, $_POST, $_SESSION, etc. variables.

Using Timber, is there a similar method? I can use Timber\URLHelper's get_params() method to access $_GET variables, but that's about all I can seem to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked through the source code and at least found the answer for $_GET and $_POST variables, so here it is if it helps anyone.

To access $_POST variables, use this:

```
{{ request.post.name_of_var }}
```

To access $_GET variables, use this:

```
{{ request.get.name_of_var }}
```

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @WasimA. What version of Timber/Twig/Wordpress are you using?  Try printing all requests vars with `<pre>{{ request|print_r }}</pre>` in your Twig template and maybe try adding a string parameter to your URL like `?some=vars` just to see if it shows up in `request.get`.

Comment: nothing, {{request}} is empty. using timber 1.20.0

Comment: @WasimA. And you're certain there are existing request variables?  (For example, you could add a get var by adding `?hello=world` to the URL.)

Comment: yes obviously :-)

Comment: @WasimA. That's odd. I'm using the same version and it's still working fine for me.  You might want to submit a [support ticket](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues).

Comment: The request var is empty if you don't use Timber::context() for the template args.

Comment: Update 2023: this method does not work in Timber 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have used $_GET variable that I can show how I have use.

For example: In a Application page data is send to another page let say thank you page by the href in anchor link. then the code for anchor link look like be:

```
<a href="/application/?job_title=Manager&amp;job_type=Part-time">Apply now</a>
```

if dynamic variable are passed then It should look like:

```
<a href="/application/?job_title={{post.title}}&amp;job_type={{post.type}}">Apply now</a>
```

Then on Thank you page it look like:

```
{% for myJob in request.get %}
    <span>{{myJob.job_title}}</span>
    <span>{{myJob.type}}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

if we need both key and value then It will be:

```
{% for key,value in request.get %}
    <span>{{key}}:{{value}}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Remember: The variable we get in the Thank You Page is what we have on Application page if it is array then we need a for loop to run through all elements and if it is a single element then no need for look then simply, it will be like:

```
{{request.get.job_title}}
```