# Setting echo $_GET inside of a form

Tags: twig, timber

I have the following set up below.

My issue is I'm not sure how to convert an inline `echo $_GET`.  Is it just the same as `{{ fn( echo $_GET['units'] === 'Miles' ? 'selected' : null ) }}`??

```
<form method="get" action="{{ post.link }}">
    <div>
        <span>Find a Store within</span>
        <input name="proximity" type="number" placeholder="15" value="<?php echo $_GET['proximity'] ?>" />
            <select name="units">
                <option value="Miles" <?php echo $_GET['units'] === 'Miles' ? 'selected' : null; ?>>Miles</option>
                <option value="K" <?php echo $_GET['units'] === 'K' ? 'selected' : null; ?>>Km</option>
            </select>
            <span>from</span>
        <input name="origin" type="text" placeholder="Your Address" value="<?php echo $_GET['origin'] ?>" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        <a href="{{ post.link }}">Reset</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing PHP global variables via Twig/Timber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810653/passing-php-global-variables-via-twig-timber)

Comment: @DarkBee that's it and thanks for reference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DarkBee for pointing the above out: [Passing PHP global variables via Twig/Timber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810653/passing-php-global-variables-via-twig-timber)

To access $_POST variables, use this:

```
{{ request.post.name_of_var }}
```

To access $_GET variables, use this:

```
{{ request.get.name_of_var }}
```

So that would make this:

```
<input name="origin" type="text" placeholder="Your Address" value="<?php echo $_GET['origin'] ?>" />
```

Be this:

```
<input name="origin" type="text" placeholder="Your Address" value="{{ request.get.origin}}
```